# Where to store all the logic of the form's controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating `WindowsForm` app now and have a `Form`. For example, at this form i have a lot of different controls like, `buttons`, `labels`, `panels`, `comboBoxes` and etc. Most of the controls have events like `doubleClick`, `dragAndDrop` and etc. So the question is where should i store all the logic for this events? I can store it of course inside the methods that implement this evenets like `btnOpen_Click()` and etc. It works fine, but is it right? Cause all the logic will be now only at one file `Form1.cs`. Or maybe i should create some kind of a static classes for that? Usually i'm creating separate classes for storing and working with specific data, but at this case, when we need to store only logic i'm kind a stuck. If it's possible, can you provide some examples please or links of good looking code or materials to read in the internet? I tried to find something by myself, but i couldn't form my question for short searcher form.

Comment: If you're used to MVC/MVVM/Other similar, these are also available in WinForms. If this is a small Project, you can simply use some separate classes to handle that logic. You can add the delegates directly in code, *inject* a class, or call methods.

Comment: @Jimi I didn't used it, but i will read about that at the internet, thank you. 
About separation, i'm working for example with panel, and i'm adding and deleting data there, so should i create one class for working with this panel? Is it should be static? Project is not so small, actually, but not giant.

Comment: It's quite improbable to suggest something meaningful knowing nothing about you or your project. If you're new to WinForms, it's actually good that you're having these doubts, but it's too brad a question to answer it properly. In any case, take a look at this: [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/). You may find it quite useful or too complex, so probably useless. Who knows :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a 'right' way.  The approach I used in the past when developing in large WinForms applications was to create custom controls then the control logic could be encapsulated in the control classes.  Even if the control simply inherits from a standard control.

Comment: I am **exactly the same! :)**